# JavaScript events for mobile web?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, dom-events

There are JavaScript events for desktop web, e.g. mouse over, key press, etc. etc.
My question is why there is no JavaScript events for mobile web? e.g. fling? orientation change? etc. etc.

What if a web developer wants to write web pages specifically for mobile devices? How can they take advantage of phone specified user interaction (like the ones I mentioned)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery and other mobile application frameworks offer extended events for mobile devices. See some of the options below:

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Answer (score 0):

> There are JavaScript events for desktop web, e.g. mouse over, key press, etc.etc. My question is why there is no JavaScript events for mobile web?

There have been (relatively speaking) decent web browsers for desktops for a lot longer then there have been decent web browsers for mobile devices, so these things haven't been standardised. That doesn't mean they don't exist though.

A decade later and they are well supported and standardised.

Some events you can listen for include [`touchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event), [`ScreenOrientation.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation), and [`devicemotion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicemotion_event)